# Swift - PanGesture Recognizer - move with object - speed of movement

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I am using PanGesture Recognizer in Swift for iOS. Inside the action method, I am calling 3rd party method, that takes move direction and speed. From this, it calculates position of object:

```
objectPos += normalize(move) * speed
```

Problem is, that if I put my finger on a certain object and move with fingers, objects is not at the same position under my finger. It starts to move slower / faster. Moving directions are OK. Problem is with acceleration / decceleration - if I move faster, objects move faster.

In gesture callback I have tried:

```
let move = recognizer.translation(in: self.view);
let speed = sqrt((move.x * move.x) + (move.y * move.y));
```

and

```
let move = recognizer.velocity(in: self.view);
let speed = dt * sqrt((move.x * move.x) + (move.y * move.y));
```

Usually `dt = 1.0 / 60.0`. It is the gesture callback refresh rate (in code, I am calculating dt manually using difference of `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()`). Without this, If I use velocity directly to calculate speed, movement is too fast.

I have tried to calculate difference manually by subtracting current and last position, but still no luck.

I have also tried to "change speed" accoring to current view width and height, but none ot if worked. I am probably missing something, but dont know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I have found the problem. Movement of th eobject it in screen normalized coordinates with corners [0,0] - [1,1]. So movement in Y axis (height) was correct, but in X axis (width) the speed was about half.

Multiply move.x with correct aspect ratio solved the problem. Basically, the moevement in X axis is enlarged manually.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you just computed the moves of the object based on acceleration when the user stops touching the object.

As long as the user has their finger on the object, it is much easier to just set the position of the object to the position you get from the pan gesture recognizer.

Comment: I cannot do this, because the 3rd party library I am using is not supporting it.

Comment: I agree with this answer, can you not send a value to neutralize the speed as long as user has the touch ? like setting dt to 1.0 instead of 1.0/60.0

Comment: which library you use?